# How to create cool ethereum wallet address?

Tags: addresses

Someone was receiving payment to a cool ethereum address kind of

`0x00000000000000000000000000002448`

How to create such address ? could that be a wallet or contract ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is a vanity address. You can use a [vanity address generator](https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/VanityEth) ([or another](https://github.com/Limeth/ethaddrgen)) to basically brute force a whole bunch of random addresses until one is created that meets your specifications (contains a certain string of characters).

The longer the string of characters is that you want to generate, the more computing power will be required to find a valid match.